# Blazor server side the binded value to an input is empty when using OnKeyDown

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

A input binded to the property `CodeInput` of my model. When I press `Tab`, I would like add the `Model.CodeInput` to `Model.Codes`.

1. I enter a caracter `'A'`, I press `tab` the `Model.CodeInput` is empty on line `Model.Codes.Add(Model.CodeInput)`
2. I enter a second caracter `'AB'`, I press tab in the `Model.CodeInput` I get `'A'`
3. I enter a third caracter `'ABC'`, in the Model.CodeInput I get `'AB'`

this lag comes from where ?

Thanks,

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string CodeInput { get; set; }
    public List<string> Codes { get; set; }
}
```

I create a component MyComponenent :

```
<CascadingValue Value=@Model>
    <Component1 />
</CascadingValue>
```

with this in code section :

```
public MyModemModel { get; set; } = new();
```

Component1.razor.cs

```
public partial class Component1 
{
    [CascadingParameter]
    public MyModel Model { get; set; }

    public void OnKeyDown(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Code == "Tab")
        {
            Model.Codes.Add(Model.CodeInput);
        }
    }
}
```

Component1.razor

```
    <MudTextField 
        @bind-Value=Model.CodeInput
        @onkeydown="OnKeyDown" />
```

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, variable @bind-Value is not updated when "Tab" is pressed. https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/caGdEKGEIwuYOKlp

Comment: @maciek Is there workaround for this ? I have exactly the same problem with "Enter". In fact that's work but with a lag input as explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `MudTextField` updates the value when it loses focus, which means after `OnKeyDown` is executed. You can use `Immediate="true"` for it to update on every input.

You should probably use debouncing if a long task is done when the value changes to avoid unnecessary calculation.

```
<MudTextField 
        Immediate="true"
        @bind-Value=Model.CodeInput
        @onkeydown="OnKeyDown" />
```

[Documentation](https://mudblazor.com/components/textfield#immediate-vs-debounced)